# \prevdepth and \noalign

Tags: tex-core

In *The TeXBook* it says

> The value of `\prevdepth` at the time of the `\halign` is used at the
>   beginning of the internal vertical list, and the final value of
>   `\prevdepth` is carried to the enclosing vertical list when the
>   alignment is completed, so that the interline glue is calculated
>   properly at the beginning and end of the alignment.

In section 15.2 of *TeX by Topic*, it says

> At the beginning of a vertical list `\prevdepth` is set to `-1000pt`,
>   except in an `\halign` and `\noalign` code contained therein, where it
>   is carried over from the surrounding list.

I'm able to understand the sentence in *The TeXBook*, but could not understand the sentence in *TeX by Topic*. Could someone give some examples about `\prevdepth` and `\noalign`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this plain tex file

```
\def\foo#1{\edef\tmp{\immediate\write20{#1: \the\prevdepth}}\tmp}


\foo{1}
g


\foo{2}

\vbox{
\foo{3}

Q

\foo{4}
}

\foo{5}

a,

\foo{6}

\halign{#\hfil\cr
\noalign{\foo{7}}
 z\cr}

\foo{8}


\bye
```

produces

```
1: -1000.0pt
2: 1.94444pt
3: -1000.0pt
4: 1.94444pt
5: 1.94444pt
6: 1.94444pt
7: 1.94444pt
8: 0.0pt
```

showing that `\prevdepth` has the magic -1000pt value at the start of the main vertical list and at the start of a `\vbox` but not in the `\noalign`.

Comment: Why couldn't I write `\def\foo#1{#1: \the\prevdepth}` instead?

Comment: @Z.H. it could, if you wanted the results typeset, rather that sent to the terminal

Answer (score 3):

Your two citations from two books solves slight different problem. The first one (from TeXbook) says that vertical material from `\halign` behaves as "normal" vertical material inside (may be greater) vertical list. It doesn't behave as `\unvbox` material where the lineskip before and after must be solved individually. The second one (from TeX by topics) says that lines from `\halign` *including objects from `\noalign` material* are connected each to next by right interlineskip. That the `\noalign` material isn't individual vertical list from this point of view.